# How to get a single row for each customer based on highest value in another column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains some customer information:

```
--------------------------------------------
|CustID  CustType  OrderType  CountofOrders|
|------------------------------------------|
|  1        C         DD          23       |
|  2       IC         DE          10       |
|  2       IC         DR           7       |
|  2       IC         DS           7       |
|  3        C         DR          14       |
|  3        C         DS          19       |
|  4       IC         DS           5       |
|  4       IC         DR           5       |
|  4       IC         DE           3       |
|  5       IC         DR           7       |
|  5       IC         DS           7       |
|  5       IC         DE           7       |
--------------------------------------------
```

I want to pull all records for Customers when CustType is not 'IC', regardless of how many rows they have.

So for instance, CustID 1 would return 1 row while CustID 3 would return 2 rows.
When the CustType is 'IC', I only want to pull a single row for that customer based on the highest CountofOrders.

So for CustID 2, it should pull the record with OrderType 'DE' and CountofOrders as 10.

If the 'IC' customer has the same count for the various OrderTypes, then I want to get the row where the OrderType is 'DE'. If the OrderType is not 'DE', then I want to get the row with the OrderType as 'DS'. In short, priority should be given to OrderType 'DE', followed by 'DS', 'DR' and 'DD'

So my final output should look something like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
|CustID  CustType  OrderType  CountofOrders|
-------------------------------------------|
|  1        C         DD           23      |
|  2       IC         DE           10      |
|  3        C         DR           14      |
|  3        C         DS           19      |
|  4       IC         DS            5      |
|  5       IC         DE            7      |
--------------------------------------------
```

I was able to use the following query to get the highest for when the CountofOrders is not the same, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get a row based on the OrderType when the CountofOrders is the same between the different OrderTypes.

```
SELECT 
    a.CustID, a.CustType, a.OrderType, a.CountofOrders
FROM 
    CustInfo a 
WHERE 
    a.CountofOrders = (SELECT MAX(CountofOrders) 
                       FROM CustInfo b 
                       WHERE a.CustID = b.CustID)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a table with OrderTypes and their priorities? Priority would be 1 for DE, 2 for DS, etc...

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What happens when there are both "IC" and "C" for the same customer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using ROW_NUMBER pretty easily. This returns the results you stated you wanted from your sample data.

```
DECLARE @Customer table
(
    CustID int
    , CustType varchar(10)
    , OrderType char(2)
    , CountofOrders int
)

INSERT @Customer
(
    CustID
    , CustType
    , OrderType
    , CountofOrders
)
VALUES
(1, 'C', 'DD', 23)
, (2, 'IC', 'DE', 10)
, (2, 'IC', 'DR', 7)
, (2, 'IC', 'DS', 7)
, (3, 'C', 'DR', 14)
, (3, 'C', 'DS', 19)
, (4, 'IC', 'DS', 5)
, (4, 'IC', 'DR', 5)
, (4, 'IC', 'DE', 3)
, (5, 'IC', 'DR', 7)
, (5, 'IC', 'DS', 7)
, (5, 'IC', 'DE', 7)

SELECT x.CustID
    , x.CustType
    , x.OrderType
    , x.CountofOrders
FROM
(
    SELECT *
         , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by CustID order by CountOfOrders desc
            , case OrderType 
                when 'DE' then 1
                when 'DS' then 2
                when 'DR' then 3
                when 'DD' then 4
                else 5
            end) as RowNum
    FROM @Customer
) x
WHERE x.CustType <> 'IC'
    OR x.RowNum = 1
ORDER BY CustID
    , CountofOrders
```

Comment: Nice solution with the OR...  ashamed to reveal my initial thoughts.  +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti no need to be ashamed. You post a LOT of really excellent solutions.

Comment: I nothing else, my answer would have some entertainment value for you folks.  :)

Comment: Looks like missing ..`case OrderType 
                                 when 'DE' then 1
                                 when 'DS' then 2
                                 when 'DR' then 3 end` in OVER to handle equal `CountOfOrders`

Comment: @Serg I thought the same thing but the desired output from the OP does not match the stated requirements. Notice for CustID 3 that DR is listed above DS which contradicts the stated rules. Either way the ordering is pretty trivial once you have the correct rows. :)

Comment: Hi @SeanLange, Thanks you for your help. Your solution does give me one of every row for when the CountofOrders is the same for different OrderTypes for 'IC' customers. However, is there a way to assign priority on which OrderType is pulled when the CountofOrders is the same between them?

Comment: @WillAce sure that is easy enough. You can add an additional predicate to the ORDER BY portion of the ROW_NUMBER window function. I updated which should now be exactly what you stated you need.

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity. If the CountofOrders is the same for the highest CountofOrders, then I want to be able to assign priority based on the different OrderTypes. So, for CustID 4, even though 'DE' should be a priority, it only has a count of 3, whereas 'DR' and 'DS' have a count of 5. In that case, between DR and DS, I would like to get the record with DS. For CustID 5, since DR, DS and DE all have the same highest count, in that case, I would like to select DE. Hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks @SeanLange. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Happy to help. Sorry it took me a bit to understand the sorting thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirement cannot be done in query level because the order is based on priority. I mean you have to use something like stored procedure or do the ordering process in your application